# JS Cloud functions error with absolute path import

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a typescript project like this with some cloud functions

```
tsconfig.json
/functions
|--index.ts
|--package.json
/src
|--App.tsx
```

In my App.tsx folders all import are absolute with this code in my tsconfig.json :

```
    "baseUrl": "../src",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["*"]
    }
```

Example of an absolute import in my App.tsx :

```
import { theme } from 'src/utils/theme/theme'
```

But in my cloud functions i need to import some file from my /src directory and i am not able to import it
I have an error after start "firebase serve" :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'src/utils/theme/theme'
```

I don't know how to fix the current path in cloud functions to import all my file with absolute path

Thanks for help

Comment: try by including the modules on your package.json and then import is as usual. [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs#including_local_nodejs_modules_as_part_of_your_deployment_package) it says how

Comment: @Lionel, in my experience with firebase functions, I was only able to reference files in the /functions directory and since your src/ directory is not in your functions directory, I'm not sure that you'll be able to reference any files in src/ for your cloud functions. I've had to resort to cloning files which has been frustrating.